# Avoid MySql Omitting + sign while insert operation

Tags: php, android, mysql

MySql Database and Tables and Columns holding `utf8_unicode_ci` collation. And this is how i am inserting a row in mysql table via core PHP :

> This is a core PHP code on server page file named getregister.php

```
$Insert = $con->query("INSERT INTO `USERS` (`ID`, `NAME`, `PHONE`, `CODE`) VALUES (NULL, '$NewUserName', '$NewUserMobile', '$UserCode')");
if ($Insert === false)
{
     echo "REPORT DEVELOPER EXCEPTION_CODE_7";
     exit();
}
else
{
     echo "SUCCESS_NEW"; 
     exit();
}
```

From the android device layouts `Edittext`, i am allowing end users, 0 to 9 with `+ Character too` :

> This is a native android code for edittext XML

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/UserPhone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/UserName"
        android:hint="NUMBER  HERE.."
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        app:met_iconPadding="0dp"
        app:met_iconRight="@drawable/ic_phone"
        app:met_minCharacters="10"
        app:met_maxCharacters="20"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:digits="0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,+"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
```

And this is how i am opening connection to servers PHP page :

> This is a java code and appropriate java code to the layout

```
String urlParameters = "DEVICEID="+deviceid+"&NAME="+name+"&PHONE="+phone+"&CODE="+code;
URL url = new URL("https://example.com/getregister.php");
connection = url.openConnection();
connection.setDoOutput(true);

OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());

writer.write(urlParameters);
writer.flush();

Log.d("GetRegistered : ", "OPENING : "+ url +" \n");

InputStream is = null;
is = connection.getInputStream();
```

Everything is working good as expected; but the problem is :

- If i enters mobile number as +919999999999
- It gets stored in MySql as WHITE_SPACE_919999999999
- The + Sign is getting deleted and replaced by a whitespace either while inserting in MySql or from androids OpenConnection

Thanks in advance, for reading, helping and giving your valuable time

> Edit : 2

As per the @jeroen given me hint about UTF8 encoding, i made some changes accordingly to the java code in android studio project to my http open url connection as follows :

```
URL url = new URL("https://www.example.com/getregister.php");
        HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);

        Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
                .appendQueryParameter("DEVICEID", deviceid)
                .appendQueryParameter("NAME", name)
                .appendQueryParameter("PHONE", phone)
                .appendQueryParameter("CODE", code);

        String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();

        OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(query);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();

        connection.connect();
```

And now + character is getting stored in the MySql.

Comment: Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Comment: First Debug Step: Do a `var_dump($_POST)` in the PHP to see what is actually getting to the PHP Script

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I am using mysqli_real_escape($con, POST(VAR), please concentrate on the main issue

Comment: You have to encode the URL parameters as URL characters, see: http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3986.html Your code doesn't look like PHP, (is it Javascript?), so I can't help you with an exact function.

Comment: See Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) _Concentrate on your users security and privacy_

Comment: @KIKOSoftware, I am editing question so that users will get which language code is this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to the comments below your question: You are manually building a query string and some characters in a query string have a special meaning, like the `&`, `=` but also the `+` which is an encoded space.

So to send the real values in the query string, you need to encode them correctly.

In this case for example `deviceid` should be `URLEncoder.encode(deviceid, "utf-8")` and so on for all the other values as well.

Comment: @jeron, Yes it helped me to meet the solution, i used it as hint. Thanks for the focusing on the problem, within the crowd of downvoters, who even does not takes efforts to read